# scene ignores the object in render however view port doesn't?

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes, tracking

i wanted to make a gun being showcased using motion tracking in Blender. However after i ran a test render i realized the object wasn't even visible so here i am to ask what the problem could be, im on the right layer and i have the objects in the right folder also every of these objects is set to visible at render. Anyone knows how to fix this?
[image: the scene]

[image: the render]

Comment: Make sure under post processing use sequencer is*not* checked

Comment: ok now i can see the gun or the background but not both of them... wich is.... wired. ill just finish the gun and make another project i guess

Comment: Sounds weird, screenshot might help